# release memory on heap, special tree

Tags: c, memory, tree, heap-memory, free

I have a tree structure
node {node * left, node * right}.
i filled it this way :
let's say A is the root.
A1 and A2 the children.
then A11 and A12 and are the children of A11.
and finally A12(=A21) and A22 the children of A22.
so A11 and A12 have one common children, and I didnt duplicate the child, we just have A12 = A21 (in term of addresses).
however to release the tree, the only way I have is to use the recursif function :
to release the tree T (which is represented by a pointer node*), Release both sub-children if they exist(i.e not NULL), then use free(T).
the problem is that when the recursif call is on A21, the pointer will be already released (because A21 = A12 and the recursif call on A12 is made before) which causes problem.
how can I fix it? 
thanks.

EDIT.
i tried to fix it by adding a new field in the structure which represent the right brother,
and it probably works since valgrind didn't notice any loss of memory :D .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    struct node *lc, *rc, *bro; // left child, right child, brother
};
typedef struct node node;

void release(node *n)
{
    if(n->lc)
        release(n->lc);
    if(n->rc){
        if(n->bro) // in that case, n and n->bro have a common node
            n->bro->lc = NULL; // so i set it to NULL because it must be released only once
        release(n->rc);
    }
    free(n);
}

int main()
{
    node *A22 = malloc(sizeof *A22);
    A22->lc = A22->rc = A22->bro = NULL;

    node *A21 = malloc(sizeof *A21);
    A21->lc = A21->rc = NULL;
    A21->bro = A22;

    node *A2 = malloc(sizeof *A2);
    A2->lc = A21;
    A2->rc = A22;
    A2->bro = NULL;

    node *A11 = malloc(sizeof *A11);
    A11->lc = A11->rc = NULL;
    A11->bro = A11;

    node *A12 = A21; // the duplicated node

    node *A1 = malloc(sizeof *A1);
    A1->lc = A11;
    A1->rc = A12;
    A1->bro = A2;

    node *A = malloc(sizeof *A); // root
    A->lc = A1;
    A->rc = A2;
    A->bro = NULL;

    release(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: any code/code snippet?

Comment: It isn't clear how you are deciding when to "re-use" children.

Answer (score 0):

Its crude, but you could maintain a global list of the nodes freed (by the address of each), so that you could refer to it and avoid re-freeing any nodes.